# Сохранение открытого экселевского файла

Tags: vbscript

Необходимо сохранить открытый экселевский файл в тот же каталог, откуда он был открыт. Имя файлу задать равное текущей дате. Буду рад любой помощи! Заранее спасибо!

```
Sub vv()
Dim xlON
dim xlNN
dim xlExt
dim dat
Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
On Error Resume Next
Set xldoc = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook<br>
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
  Wscript.Echo "Ошибка открытия целевого документа"
  Exit Sub
End If
xlPath = xldoc.Path
xlON = xldoc.Name
dat = Format("dd-mm-yy", Now())
xlExt = Right(xlON, InStrRev(xlON, ".") - 1)
xlNN = Left(xlON, InStr(xlON, ".") - 1)
xldoc.SaveAs Filename = xlNN & dat & xlExt
End Sub
```

Пытаюсь сделать так, но ничего не происходит... В чем может быть ошибка?

Comment: @Lander, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: поправил, скинул код, что я пытался сделать

Comment: @Lander, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub WorkbookSave()
Dim sPath As String
Dim sName As String
    sPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/"
    sName = Format(Date, "dd-mm-yy")

    With ActiveWorkbook 
        .SaveAs sPath & sName, xlWorkbookNormal, CreateBackup:=False
    End With
End Sub
```

*ActiveWorkbook.Path* - для примера, в переменной должен храниться путь, записанный при открытии книги.